# Stream PDF content to browser in PHP (not a file)

Tags: php, pdf

I already know how to display a PDF file in a browser with PHP.
My system gets the PDF from a webservice, then I save this content in a variable. Now I have to save this PDF as a file to show in a browser. How can I show the variable content directly to browser without saving a file in server filesystem?

Thanks a lot!

Today I save the PDF on the server's filesystem tho show in a browser. When I get the PDF from webservice I want to show straight in browser, without saving.

Comment: Just output the appropriate response headers, followed by the PDF content ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/45466043/1427878